# How to switch a netbook desktop on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-netbook

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. My screen is quite small, and I think that the netbook desktop ([something like this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UNR?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=unr-favorites-small.png)) would be better. Is it possible to switch to netbook desktop on Ubuntu 12.04? If so, how is that done? (Or have I understood it all wrong...?)

Comment: This was removed in 11.04 as "Ubuntu Netbook" merged into Unity

Comment: **What is your netbook's screen resolution?**  I have no great difficulties on an HP Mini 210 (1024 × 600), with **Ubuntu 12.04** and Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That desktop option is not available since Ubuntu 11.04.

The Ubuntu Netbook Edition was introduced in Ubuntu 8.04, since Ubuntu 10.10 started using Unity the Netbook interface was set aside as an option only and since Ubuntu 11.04 you cannot install it anymore.

Unity should adapt it self for your screen's resolution and most of the times it looks nice enough to use it. If you do not agree and you need something more sleek maybe Kubuntu with it's Netbook plasma desktop is something to consider

[image]

At least you will be running the latest Ubuntu has to offer.

Comment: Ok, I'll propably try that. But anyway, thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: @Ville if you want to have a look at other options available http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available is a list of available desktop environments for Ubuntu. Not all of them are top shape and the information might be a bit outdated  but at least you can have a look.

Answer (score -2):

For netbooks I'll better prefer on netbook usage, EasyPeasy Ubuntu flavor which supports cloud computing and less resources usage with a better and more reliable Desktop and great GUI. EasyPeasy is what really you need as netbook desktop.

Link to download page:
http://www.geteasypeasy.com/get-easypeasy/

Comment: Ok, this discussion is going not further than this, please read the FAQ about what should be on topic on this site and how the site works. Regards

Comment: Hence proved you were wrong thats why found it best to remove the convo... nice job btw ;)

Comment: Dude, now you are being rude. FYI Easy Peasy 2 does not use the netbook look anymore, it uses GNOME3 Shell, have a [look](http://www.geteasypeasy.com/easypeasy-2-0-alpha-released/). I do not know why do you need to bash your head on this: Easy Peasy 1.6 is old, for that it is better to recommend Ubuntu 10.04 which had security updates till now, and Easy Peasy 2 alpha uses GNOME3 Shell and that can be installed in Ubuntu without any need to use another distribution. Instead of calling other people ignorant and linking random stuff be nice to people when they tell you something next time.